# UIActivity with no settings for Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, uiactivity, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is it possible to show Facebook `UIActivity` in `UIActivityViewController` if there's no settings for facebook account in default iOS settings? For now if I enter some fb account - I see fb in `UIActivityViewController`, if no - not see. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No it's not possible... If Facebook is not set up in `Settings > Facebook`, then the `UIActivityViewController` will not show Facebook as an option to share.

Comment: thx) i thought so, but need to sure, mb there's some workaround, sad

Comment: But why would you give Facebook as an option when the user isn't using Facebook? If you're looking for a kind of log in prompt. Then you should look into the Facebook SDK and prompt login if theres no session

Comment: On photos app, there's always a facebook button. When user is not logged, it prompts to change settings. It's a nice feature...

Comment: On the apple pre installed apps, both twitter and Facebook should always appear, tapping them without an account set up in settings prompts you to do so. When the share controller is used in third party apps, it only shows available services.

Comment: On the iOS Simulator, if you present a UIActivityViewController, the Facebook icon appears regardless if the user is logged in or not. If the user taps Facebook, they are shown the Share Screen, and a UIAlert appears informing them they must login to share, and they can hit the "Settings" button, which brings them to the Facebook Login in Settings. iOS 6.

Comment: Is there a way to get a reference to the UIActivity of the built-in types to pass as an arg to applicationActivities?  For example, get a reference to the UIActivity corresponding to UIActivityTypePostToFacebook?

Comment: @Wayfarer I wish that was the device default behaviour

Comment: You should let Apple know that this is something you'd like to see changed: http://bugreporter.apple.com/

Answer (score 6):

It's possible with another view controller called OWActivityViewController https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController

It works for me!

Comment: It is ios6 style what if I want ios7 and 8 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451583/uiactivityview-controller-behaviour-is-strange